# Iterate through a sequence of operators

Tags: python, testing, operator-keyword

Is it possible/Is there a way to iterate through a sequence of operators as in the following example?

```
a, b = 5, 7
for op in (+, -, *, /):
    print(a, str(op), b, a op b)
```

One possible use case is the test of the implementation of various operators on some abstract data type where these operators are overloaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the operator module.

```
for op in [('+', operator.add), ('-', operator.sub), ('*', operator.mul), ('/', operator.div)]:
    print("{} {} {} = {}".format(a, op[0], b, op[1](a, b)))
```

Comment: I prefer this as I don't need to rewrite the various operators, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own operations, then iterate through them.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    return a / b
a, b = 5, 7

operations = {'+': add,'-': sub, '*':mult, '/': div}
for op in operations:
    print(a, op, b, operations[op](a, b))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: The eval approach was more straightforward for simple  (binary infix) operations and avoided defining all those functions. Now,when the operations are more complex of course, I can't avoid that. Acknowledged the 'avoid eval' part.

Comment: @zetysz: Yeah :), about `eval`, it's really dangerous. So don't use it ***forever***.

Comment: @KevinGuan In the use case I mentioned above, namely for testing purpose, eval would only be confined in the test code. But still, if it can be avoided, let's avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a,b=5,7
for op in ['+','-','*','/']:
    exec 'print a' + op + 'b'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Douglas, thanks but `exec` is pretty much the same as `eval`.

Comment: @green diod, is there something on this page I'm not seeing?  That comment seems kind of random, am I missing something?

Comment: @green diod, nevermind, I just found the comments.  Thanks for the pointer. Why are exec and eval so dangerous? I've used them a lot, I wasn't aware of this.