# Python binary to unary function

Tags: python, unary-operator, binary-operators

Following this thread about [iterating through a sequence of operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312846/iterate-through-a-sequence-of-operators#), I want also to take care of unary operators in the same sequence. I used a lambda function to get rid of the second argument but are there special purpose tools/libraries for that in Python?

```
a, b = 5, 7
for op in [('+', operator.add), ('-', lambda x, y: operator.neg(x))]:
    print("{} {} {} = {}".format(a, op[0], b, op[1](a, b)))
```

Comment: I think you should process unary and binary separatly, you want to get `5 -  7   = -5`?

Comment: @bigOTHER Yeah, that's what I want/get. Of course, I can make a separate loop for unary ops. But maybe there's a more Pythonic way/some standard library to do it. (In C++, you have bind1st and so on)

Comment: the alternative of bind1st in python is `functools.partial` but `lambda` do the job magically so prefer it. Yet, in your case , just separate it, in python base readabilty counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate the processing of binary and unary operators.

```
a, b = 5, 7
# binary ops
for op in [('+', operator.add), ('-', operator.sub]:
    print("{} {} {} = {}".format(a, op[0], b, op[1](a, b)))

#unary ops
for op in [('-', operator.neg]:
    print("{} {} = {}".format(op[0], a, op[1](a)))
```